# How to append product id column after converting xml objects to csv in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to get this product listing (columns labels do not matter for me so don't care about them) :

```
  "produit id","code","value"
  "pdt1","123456","123456"
  "pdt1","789012","ghijkl"
  "pdt1","345678","mnopqr"
  "pdt2","111111","abcdef"
  "pdt2","789012","ghijkl"
  "pdt2","345678","mnopqr"
  "pdt3","123456","123456"
  "pdt3","789012","ghijkl"
  "pdt3","345678","mnopqr"
```

from

```
  $xml=[xml]@'
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
  <catalogue>
    <produits>
      <produit id="pdt1" libelle="produit 1" cat="PDT">
        <metas date="2015.07.24">
          <meta code="123456" value="123456"></meta>
          <meta code="789012" value="ghijkl"></meta>
          <meta code="345678" value="mnopqr"></meta>
        </metas>
      </produit>
      <produit id="pdt2" libelle="produit 2" cat="PDT">
        <metas date="2015.07.24">
          <meta code="111111" value="abcdef"></meta>
          <meta code="789012" value="ghijkl"></meta>
          <meta code="345678" value="mnopqr"></meta>
        </metas>
      </produit>
      <produit id="pdt3" libelle="produit 3" cat="PDT">
        <metas date="2015.07.24">
          <meta code="123456" value="123456"></meta>
          <meta code="789012" value="ghijkl"></meta>
          <meta code="345678" value="mnopqr"></meta>
        </metas>
      </produit>
    </produits>
  </catalogue>
  '@
```

I know how to get last 2 columns with this instruction :

```
  $xml.catalogue.produits.produit.metas.meta | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

which gives :

```
  "code","value"
  "123456","123456"
  "789012","ghijkl"
  "345678","mnopqr"
  "111111","abcdef"
  "789012","ghijkl"
  "345678","mnopqr"
  "123456","123456"
  "789012","ghijkl"
  "345678","mnopqr"
```

How to append product id column (column position does not matter for me) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the product id by iterating over the `meta` elements and for each one create a PSObject which gets the product id by referring to the id of its grandparent. For example:

```
$xml.catalogue.produits.produit.metas.meta | % { New-Object psobject -property @{ id = $_.parentnode.parentnode.id; code = $_.code; value = $_.value } } | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Output:

```
"code","id","value"
"123456","pdt1","123456"
"789012","pdt1","ghijkl"
"345678","pdt1","mnopqr"
"111111","pdt2","abcdef"
"789012","pdt2","ghijkl"
"345678","pdt2","mnopqr"
"123456","pdt3","123456"
"789012","pdt3","ghijkl"
"345678","pdt3","mnopqr"
```